# Search Query to Filter Out records from Database

Tags: sql, db2, fusion

I am entering some values on a search engine on **GUI**

```
Name, Date, State
```

If a user does not enter any value, and click on 'Search', he should get entire table from the database. i.e. no filters are applied.

So for example i wrote

```
Select Name, State, Date from Table where Name='' and State= '' and Date= ''
```

But if i enter no values in GUI, no records are fetched from DB. **But i want these to act as filters and not conditions.**
I am using DB2

Please suggest me the correct way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following query would be correct for this purpose,

```
Select Name, State, Date 
from Table 
where (:Name_Var is null OR Name = :Name_Var AND 
      (:State_Var is null OR State =:State_Var) AND 
      (:Date_Var is null OR Date = :Date_Var)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Name, State, Date 
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Name,0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE Name END = ISNULL(@Name,0) 
    AND 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@State,0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE State END = ISNULL(@State,0) 
    AND 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(@Date,0)=0 THEN 0 ELSE Date END = ISNULL(@Date,0)
```